# C++ shared library import on micropython for stm32

Tags: c++, shared-libraries, micropython, .so

I have a C++ project that I would like to include into the firmware of my pyboard.

The C++ project has an ffi interface which allows me to build a shared library and then access it from python using the ctypes library. However, micropython used on **STM32** does not include ctypes or ffi libraries.

Any ideas on how I can proceed with this ?

Comment: forget about shared libraries, micropython, ctypes and ffi on uCs.

Comment: In the fact forget about most of the large computer stuff (including the dynamic allocation). Micropython is good as something interesting, but with no practical use.

Comment: @P__J__ speak for yourself, we use it daily in production. Quite practical. :P That being said: you could write a MicroPython wrapper for the part of the C++ functionality you need. No ffi or so, just expose some functionality as MicroPython types. Bit hard to give more dedicated info for such a general question but look at e.g. http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/develop/cmodules.html for a start. That's for C but you can build your C++ part as static or shared library and add it.

Comment: @stijn, thanks for the reply. Say, I have wrapped my C++ header files and created a shared library. However, I cannot find any examples where they add a shared library into the .mk file. Any leads for that ?
Apologies if it is still vague, I have been trying to play around with the tools available but no success yet

Comment: Add needed linker flags to LDFLAGS_USERMOD in your module's .mk file.

Comment: @stijn, I am trying to link a library that requires the C++ standard library.
I link it in the LDFLAGS_USERMOD as /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a. But I get the error: arm-none-eabi-ld: error: build-PYBV11/firmware.elf uses VFP register arguments, /usr/arm-none-eabi/lib/libstdc++.a(chrono.o) does not. I understand the error but am not sure how to solve this issue since I simply downloaded the libstdc++ along with the toolchain.

Comment: arm-none-eabi-gcc -dumpversion: 9.2.1

Comment: Hmm, no idea sorry. Probably has to do with the way uPy builds/links. I've successfully used -lstd-c++ on the unix build for instance. Anyway: you might get better answers on the mmicroPython forum or it's github issue tracker. Not many of the developers around here on SO..